# How can I tell when a loop is done.using JavaScript and Vue and AXIOS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, axios

I have a dataGrid from Syncfusion and I have a column of checkboxes.  When I press a button the code reads all of the selected rows creates an array and loops until the process is ended.

```
         this.selectedRecords = this.$refs.grid.ej2Instances.getSelectedRecords();
         this.selectedRecords.forEach(function(arg, index) { 

         call HTTP API request. with AXIOS
         get the return values and store it to the database

         }
```

I could have 100+ rows selected and I need to be able to tell when all of the API calls are finished.

I have slowed down my calls so I only have a maximum of 10 calls per second using

```
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
          function(config) {               
            setTimeout(console.log("here request interceptor"), 100);
            return config;
          },
          function(error) {
            return Promise.reject(error);
          }
        );
```

And I have tried

```
        if (self.selectedRecords.length - 1 === index) {
          alert("Done");
        }
```

but since there is not a guarantee that the rows are processed in order it can call "Done" too early.

I hope I've given you enough code to understand my problem without giving you too much to make it sloppy.

Comment: So you determine if iteration is over by `self.selectedRecords.length - 1 === index`? How does it work? After you pass first object it clears itself from `self.selectedRecords` collection?

Comment: The record length stays the same but the index changes and an additional record is read. but not guaranteed to be in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood correctly then you should just need to gather up the promises in an array and then use `Promise.all` to wait for them to all complete:

```js
var requests = this.selectedRecords.map(function(arg, index) { 
    return axios.get(/* request details here */);
});

Promise.all(requests).then(function() {
    console.log('Done')
});
```

If you need to process the individual requests using a `then` that's fine, just chain it on the end of the `axios.get` call:

```js
return axios.get(/* request details here */)
    .then(function(response) {
        // Handle response
    })
```

**Update:**

Request interceptors can return promises, which will be necessary if you want to hold up the execution of the request:

```js
http.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve(config)
    }, 5000)
  })
})
```

Note that the example above is not performing proper throttling, it's merely delaying the request. It is purely to illustrate how promises can be used with interceptors. You haven't included the real interceptor in the question so I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I'm not 100% sure I'm using it correctly.  The Promise.all is getting called almost immediately.  If I put a breakpoint there and hover I can see all of the requests .but it then goes back and start processing the HTTP requests.

Comment: @user1314159 Have you changed the `forEach` to a `map`? Are you returning the promise from the function? Other than that my only thought is that the interceptor might be implemented incorrectly, so that the promises returned don't actually correspond to the requests. Not sure you need that throttling anyway, the browser will throttle requests if it thinks it needs to.

Comment: It now works with the interceptor removed.  The problem is that if I make more than 10 api calls in a second then my IP address is blocked.

Comment: @user1314159 I have added an update to the end of my answer to illustrate how you can use timers and interceptors together without breaking the promise chain. I have assumed that the interceptor code you included in the question was just pseudo-code as it's a long way from being working throttling.

Comment: Works great-- I set the Timeout to 120 and that is all I need to slow it down a bit.  And now at the completion I can make another call and populate the datatable. Thanks